# How to restrict child classes from modifying the scope of a method in Abstract class?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, scope

How can I restrict the implementation class of my Abstract class from modifying the scope of a method from protected to public?

For example : Suppose I have a Abstract Class

```
package com.rao.test;

public abstract  class AbstractTEClass {

    protected abstract void function1();

    protected abstract void function2();


    protected void doWork() //I want to call the abstract methods from this method.
    {
        function1(); //implementation classes will give implementation of these methods
        function2();

    }

}
```

Now, I have a implementation class which extends the above abstract class

```
package com.rao.test;

public class AbstractTEClassImpl extends AbstractTEClass {

    @Override
    public void function1() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("FUnction1");
    }

    @Override
    public void function2() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Function2");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        AbstractTEClassImpl objTEClass = new AbstractTEClassImpl();

        objTEClass.doWork();

    }

}
```

**Notice here that I am changing the scope of the 2 abstract methods in the implementation class from protected to public, how can I restrict my implementation class from modifying the scope. 

Any design changes or recommendation or patterns are welcome.**

Comment: why do you want to set this restriction? maybe you're on the wrong way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.  I suspect what you want to do is fiddle with `doWork()` so it can survive any abuse extending classes might do inside the function1 and 2 overrides.  You might want to add methods and/or change what those methods do.

Overriding is a handy thing.  I often get real annoyed working in C# because Microsoft "seals" everything to prevent overriding.  (I exaggerate; they only seal the methods *I* want to override.)  Don't go that route.  Figure out what your real problem is and handle it in your base AbstractTEClass class.

Answer (score 6):

You can't.

An overriding class can always give more access to a method than the method it's overriding.

Read the section on modifiers here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html

> The access specifier for an overriding method can allow more, but not less, access than the overridden method. For example, a protected instance method in the superclass can be made public, but not private, in the subclass.
>
> You will get a compile-time error if you attempt to change an instance method in the superclass to a class method in the subclass, and vice versa.

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to do that. And I don't see the point either: if the subclass wants to make this method accessible, why shouldn't it? It won't affect users of the parent abstract class anyway.

Comment: And even if you could restrict that, the subclass could create another public method that calls the protected method, exposing the behavior anyways.

Comment: I was about to edit my answer to say exactly the same thing. No need anymore :-)

Comment: I know that it cannot be done directly.Is there any workaround using design patterns using which I can achieve this???

Comment: You're using the template pattern. You could maybe use the strategy pattern instead: make the parent class non-abstract and final, and make it take a strategy argument as parameter which implements function1 and function2. I don't know if it fits your bill, because I don't know what you want to achieve.

Comment: That said, I'm pretty sure there's no way to really even approximate this desire.