# Why is it not allowed to narrow down scope of a method while overriding

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

In Java, when I override a method the compiler flags off any attempt to narrow down the visibility as an error. For ex: I can't override a public method as protected, while I can override a protected method as public.

I am interested in knowing the design decision/thinking behind this rule.

Comment: This question was asked a few days ago, but what would be the point?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11343763/1475461  look at this for discussion that was had last week on the issue

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A subclass should always satisfy the contract of the superclass.  See [Liskov Substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

The visibility of methods is part of this contract.  So anything publicly visible in the superclass should be public in the subclass as well.

Comment: I have one query,

Answer (score 17):

Consider a class `B` which inherits from `A`. `A.m()` is public. Now consider this code:

```
A obj = new B();
obj.m();
```

Should this call be allowed? Yes, it should, because `obj` is an object of type `A`! It is also an object of type `B`, but that is not necessarily known to the one using the object.

Every object of type `A` must adhere to the contract (interface) for `A`. `B` extends `A` and must therefore also adhere to that contract.

Answer (score 5):

While over ridding or implementing the access level, we should go for same access level or wider to that access level.

```
private < (default) < protected < public
```

Public is wider most level.

In Interface all members are default public. So, While implementing or over ridding we have to go for only public.

Answer (score 2):

Assume parent class and child class with overriding method with public access modifier.

```
class Parent{

public void m(){
// method implementation
}

}
class Child extends Parent{
@Override
public void m(){
//child implementation
}
}
```

assume there are some classes which are utilising this functionality like this

```
Parent p = new Child();
p.m(); // this access is fine, because JVM calls Overriding method at run time
```

Now if we change the access of overriding method to anything less than public

```
class Child extends Parent{
@Override
void m(){
//Child implementation
}
}
```

Now some of the classes which were able to use the functionality of method m() may not be able access the function.This is not a desired behaviour.

Hence the rule is **Overriding method should not decrease the scope of overridden method**.