# In contrast to C++, why method visibility can't be narrowed while overriding?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

The following program fails:

```
abstract class A {
  protected void method() {}
}

class B extends A {
  private void method() {}
}

public class main{
     public static void main(String []args) {}
}
```

with:

```
main.java:6: error: method() in B cannot override method() in A
  private void method() {}
               ^
  attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was protected
1 error
```

Setting the derived method to protected/private works.

**Question: What is the reason Java won't let you further restrict access in subclasses?** I contrast this to C++ which has the exact opposite rule.

Comment: See [Virtual Function in JAVA](http://www.shivasoft.in/blog/java/virtual-function-in-java/)

Comment: @Vishrant is not a duplicate. That question ask about how to accomplish that behavior in Java. This question asks **why** Java has this behavior.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: This one seems like an exact duplicate -http://stackoverflow.com/q/11484667/738746.

Comment: @BheshGurung looks like an incomplete explanation.

Comment: This is the Thumb rule of polymorphism, if user x override the method of user y and made it private then user x will loos control on his/her own method then who is going to use x method next time and what is the use of it.

Comment: @P.K普 what part of *C++ has the exact opposite rule* you didn't read on the question?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza:I am not talking about c++ the question main concern is about java.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: Agreed. It's good on mentioning the LSP, but nothing about all methods being virtual.

Comment: @P.K普 the question is why Java has this behavior unlike C++. And the explanation is that methods in Java are `virtual`. In C++, you have to declare your method as `virtual` manually to allow polymorphism. And that's the explanation.

Comment: @BheshGurung if you don't mark the method as `virtual`, it won't be overridden at all, both methods would have almost the same signature but behave different.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: I am not that well familiar with C++. But I see what you are saying. I have also edited the title, IMHO, it represents the question better now.

Comment: @BheshGurung I recommend you to practice some C++ to have a better understanding of polymorphism in other languages.

Answer (score 7):

In Java, all methods are `virtual` by default (except for `private` and `static` methods). So, when overriding a method in Java, it **must** behave with the definition in the class of the object reference. By this rule in Java, you cannot narrow the visibility of an overridden method, just maintain the same visibility or widening it.

Answer (score 5):

All Java methods are virtual.  So suppose you get an `A` that is actually an instance of `B`.  You don't know this.  You call `A.method()`, but because `method` is virtual, it tries to call `B.method()`.  But `B.method` is private, so now what?

Edit: apparently Java methods are only virtual *by default* these days, as Luiggi Mendoza points out in his answer.

Further edit: I guess the scenario I've described is one where `A.method` is public, where you had it as protected.  But you get the idea.