# Can I implement a Java interface method as private or protected?

Tags: java, interface

Is it possible to implement an interface and then when overriding the methods, make the methods `private` or `protected`?

Comment: You could just test it, and you would have the answer. It's 6 lines of code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11484667/why-is-it-not-allowed-to-narrow-down-scope-of-a-method-while-overriding

Comment: It is sarcastic comments like this that makes people who are trying to learn run away from SO. Of course I tested it, hence the reason I am asking if it is possible. Other redponses here were very helpful and even explained why it is not possible. I think perhaps you should re-evaluate why you are commenting on this platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot because there are some rules(more details are mentioned [here](https://crunchify.com/java-method-overriding-examples-and-concepts-overriding-rules/)) :

> In java, a method can only be written in Subclass, not in same class.
>
> The argument list should be exactly the same as that of the overridden
>   method.
>
> The return type should be the same or a subtype of the return type
>   declared in the original overridden method in the super class.
>
> The access level cannot be more restrictive than the overridden
>   method’s access level. For example: if the super class method is
>   declared public then the over-ridding method in the sub class cannot
>   be either private or protected.
>
> Instance methods can be overridden only if they are inherited by the
>   subclass.
>
> A method declared final cannot be overridden.
>
> A method declared static cannot be overridden but can be re-declared.
>
> If a method cannot be inherited then it cannot be overridden.
>
> A subclass within the same package as the instance’s superclass can
>   override any superclass method that is not declared private or final.
>
> A subclass in a different package can only override the non-final
>   methods declared public or protected.
>
> An overriding method can throw any uncheck exceptions, regardless of
>   whether the overridden method throws exceptions or not.
>
> However the overriding method should not throw checked exceptions that
>   are new or broader than the ones declared by the overridden method.
>   The overriding method can throw narrower or fewer exceptions than the
>   overridden method.
>
> Constructors cannot be overridden.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is very helpful!

Answer (score 3):

Interface methods are public by default (even if you don't specify it explicitly). Therefore, any method that implements an interface method must also be `public`, since you can't reduce the visibility of the method.

The reason:

Suppose you have an interface:

```
public interface SomeInterface {
    public int someMethod();
}
```

Now you implement the interface:

```
public class SomeClass implements SomeInterface {
    public int someMethod() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

And you can use it as follows:

```
SomeInterface inter = new SomeClass();
int result = inter.someMethod();
```

Now, it you changed the access level of `someMethod()` to `protected` or `private` in the implementing class, it would no longer be accessible from outside classes (for example, in won't be accessible from a class that belongs to a different package and doesn't extend `SomeClass`). However, since `SomeClass` implements `SomeInterface`, and the interface's method is `public`, it must be accessible.